# Плавное сползание до контента на javascript

Tags: jquery, javascript

Какой скрипт делает анимацию (сползание) как [здесь](http://agat-group.ru/commercial_auto/)? Где его можно найти?

Comment: Это Flash, это не скрипт...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в исходный код загляните, там все красиво написано :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop()< 479){
        if($.browser.safari){
            $('body').animate( { scrollTop: 479 }, 500 );
        }else{
            $('html').animate( { scrollTop: 479 }, 500 );
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот здесь очень хороший пример: http://szenprogs.ru/blog/plavnyj_skrolling_k_jakorju_na_jquery/2009-09-17-70
Там объясняется и что такое якорь, и как к нему сделать переход плавный на js.